# Am I allowed to freely move to Germany for my internship?

Tags: germany, internship

I am from Nepal and have been living in Finland for 3 years as a student. I have currently got an offer for an internship in Germany for 3 months. In this case, as a non-EU national living in Finland with a valid residence permit document, do I need to apply for a separate visa to move to Germany for a period of 3 months? And what if the stay period should extend by one or two days (because I have already bought the plane tickets)? It's an urgent question, and please clear suggestions would be appreciated a lot. Thanks!

Comment: You may visit any Schengen country for a maximum of 90 days during any 180 days period if you hold a vaild residence permit of a Schengen member country and have your passport. So legally the 3 months might just be covered by that, although that would be cutting it really close...